# Firefox stack trace during Flickr API request from meteor

Tags: javascript, firefox, meteor, flickr

I'm having a strange error which only happens when loading my meteor application from it's remote server in Firefox.

Navigate to the following in Chrome or Safari and the cover images of the books should show up just fine. Do so with Firefox and the images are missing. The inspector shows a stack trace but I'm unsure how to start debugging this.

https://app.mytoori.com/published

Strangely the code does work in Firefox if I run it from localhost. It could have something to do with the server config but if that's the case then it should not work in the other browsers either.

Firefox 51 (64bit) on OS X Sierra.

Below is the call that's made to get the image url from Flickr. These are then stored in a Session variable.

```
Meteor.http.call(`GET`, flickr_call, function(error, result) {
    if (error)
      console.error(`flickr call error `, error);
    else if (result.statusCode === 200 && result.data && result.data.stat === `ok`) {
      const sizes = result.data.sizes.size;
      for (let i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
        if (sizes[i].label === `Original`) {
          Session.set(cover, sizes[i].source); // eslint-disable-line
        };
      }
    }
  });
```

Tips on how to handle this better are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was WiFi related. Only Firefox had the issue  though. All other browsers were connecting just fine.

Turning WiFi off and then on again got rid of the issue.